# What am I? Be specific

Tags: riddle

I'm here for your own safety.

A variety of me can be given as a gift.

1st letter is similar to how old you are.

5th letter if removed, SE gets upset.

Comment: Too short for an answer, so: guveq yvar cebonoyl zrnaf gur yrggre "U", fbhaqf yvxr "ntr". (ROT13).

Comment: Could you maybe tell us what SE should stand for?

Comment: @Foitn - in this context, I assume Stack Exchange

Comment: Well of course, that should work...  ty :)

Comment: Maybe a hint? ;)

Comment: @Gustavo hasn't even been 12 hours yet. I was told to wait 24...

Comment: Yep we don’t need a hint yet. Someone may still get it without one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> Secure hypertext transport protocol, or "https"
>  "h" is like age (see gnovice's answer for that)
>  You can give gift "codes" that are often https: format, also https uses a certificate (like a gift certificate)
>  Remove the 's' on any link and it's an unsecure connection, which SE does NOT like

Comment: I posted my answer before decoding [the comment from Xenocacia above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63303/what-am-i-be-specific#comment192600_63303). Looks like they solved that part first.

Comment: V jnf guvaxvat uggcf vf n pregvsvpngr, (tvsg pregvsvpngr) nf sbe FR trggvat hcfrg. Gel nggnpuvat na vzntr (abg guebhtu vzthe) naq hfr uggc jvgubhg gur F.

Comment: @WELZ: I deleted it, since it was already covered by Xenocacia's comment and was just a partial answer.

Comment: @gnovice I didn't see the ROT13 comment, just your partial answer.  I though you deserved credit for that part.  I determined the answer based on the second and third parts, and didn't get the first part until I read yours.

Comment: @NetJohn: I guess I can undelete it. The Rep doesn't matter much since I've capped for the day, but I guess it's easier to hover over the spoiler text than cut and paste the comment into a ROT13 decoder.

Comment: The gift part is a type of cookie.

Comment: @NetJohn could you possibly edit your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Let me know if the edit is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

"1st letter is similar to how old you are."

> The first letter is **H** (pronounced similarly to "age")?

Comment: Sounds Japanese to me for some reason - the way they pronounce "age"